# Centos Service not starting

Tags: service, startup

Running Centos7, I have init.d service that I'm trying to start. When I do so it comes back with an OK message which = success. Yet when I use TOP I don't see it running.

Now if I take the command that the service should be running from the `cat /etc/init.d/XXXX` it starts as expected.

How can I go about debugging this? I've checked /messages, and /secure and even dmesg but I don't see anything amiss.

Answer (score 0):

Try `systemctl start <command>`

Eg if you want to start ssh

`systemctl start sshd`

or

`systemctl start sshd.service`

Look for man pages of systemctl

## Explaination

CentOS 7 / RHEL 7 / Fedora Linux (many other modern distor) uses Systemd. It is a system and service manager for Linux operating systems. In newer distro such as CentOS7/RHEL7 systemd replaces Upstart as the default init system

In case you have scripts for starting & stopping of a particular process or code
you can place a file `/etc/init.d/` directory
with somewhat below logic

```
#!/bin/bash

SCRIPT_PATH=/pathtoscriptdirectory

case $1 in  
start)  
sh $SCRIPT_PATH/startup.sh  
;;   
stop)     
sh $SCRIPT_PATH/shutdown.sh  
;;   
restart)  
sh $SCRIPT_PATH/shutdown.sh  
sh $SCRIPT_PATH/startup.sh  
;;   
esac      
exit 0
```

Its good practice to make start stop restart blocks, you can have your custom blocks too

Also make sure that you have executable permission over all the files in this lineup

Then run it like you run the normal services

Comment: Tried that `sudo systemctl start <command>` looks like it executed properly but still nothing running

Comment: What kind of service you are looking for ??

Comment: running `sudo -u jetty ./<command>.sh` works and I then see the jetty user when hitting `TOP`.

Comment: do you want to run a shell script as a service ??

Comment: I edited my answer, on top of services you can set path & append paths, set variables etc

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64732/discussion-between-tony-and-ashish).